# hyper v - private network , ip , vpn

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

How are ip generated in a "private" network in hyper v ?

context : i want to configure a windows vpn server (connected to this private network AND to the internet) so the vpn clients are in the private network.

thank you for helping

Comment: so the guest vm will be the vpn terminator correct?  Also the term split tunnel is what you are looking for as far as I can tell from your decription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are ip generated in a "private" network in hyper v ?

Not at all - the same way as with a physical network without hyper-v. Hyper-v does not care about yor IP addresses, it simulats hardware. SIt down and start planning the network layout like you would do for ap hysical server setup.

Comment: yea I read that part and figured he has a ways to go before he gets anywhere on this.